# Remove parentheses from lists in Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a code that removes parentheses from each top level element of the list.  For example, the input '( (1 2) (3 4) ) will produce '(1 2 3 4) and the input '((x (y)) z) should produce '(x (y) z).

Is there a way to recognize pairs of parentheses?  I was thinking I could find pairs of parentheses and remove them, but I'm not sure how to do that and also how to only remove from the top element.

Comment: Is your input a string, or a s-expression?

Comment: input is a list!

Answer (score 2):

The pattern "I am trying to (do something to) each top level element of the list" is a sure sign that `map` will be involved. Also, one big clue is in your first example case:

```
'((1 2) (3 4))  =>  '(1 2 3 4)
```

That's just `append*`!

```
(append* '((1 2) (3 4)))  =>  '(1 2 3 4)
```

But that's not the case for `'((x (y)) z)  =>  '(x (y) z)`.

```
(append* '((x (y)) z))  =>  '(x (y) . z)
```

If you think about it, `append*` is very close to what you want: it unwraps one level of parens from each element in a list. Problem is, some of the elements in your input aren't lists, so there's nothing to unwrap.

We could fix that by just wrapping each non-list element in a singleton list, so that `'((x (y)) z)` becomes `'((x (y)) (z))`. And then we can use `append*`:

```
(append* '((x (y)) (z)))  =>  '(x (y) z)
```

This is where `map` comes handy. `map` is a function that takes a function (`f`) and a list (`lst`) and returns a new list made by applying `f` to each element of `lst`. For example:

```
(map symbol? '(a 2 b c 5))  =>  '(#t #f #t #t #f)
```

Suppose you wrote a function that takes one argument and either returns it unaltered if it's a list, or else wraps it up as a singleton list if it's not. Let's call it `maybe-wrap`. Then you could map `maybe-wrap` over your input, and the result could be passed to `append*`:

```
(define (remove-parens lst)
  (append* (map maybe-wrap lst)))
```

I'll leave it to you to write `maybe-wrap`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm really new to Racket and I've never worked with / learned about maps.  But from what you're saying it seems like I could replace "some-function" with append?

Comment: @Vic Not quite. I've updated my answer. See if it's any help now.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `append` or `map`, you can define [mutually recursive](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mutual_recursion) functions to do what you want, as follows:

```
(define (unwrap lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (my-append (car lst) (cdr lst))))

(define (my-append lhs rhs)
  (cond
    [(null? lhs)
     (unwrap rhs)]
    [(pair? lhs)
     (cons (car lhs)
           (my-append (cdr lhs) rhs))]
    [else
     (cons lhs (unwrap rhs))]))
```

For example:

```
> (unwrap '((1 2) (3 4 (5 (6)))))
'(1 2 3 4 (5 (6)))
> (unwrap '((x (y)) z))
'(x (y) z)
```